# create popup window using jquery and doing an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a popup window to get the name,having a text field and a save button.

User can type their name in the text field so that the entered name should be displayed in the webpage below the `"type a name"` button.

.js file is,

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $("a.topopup").click(function() {
            loading(); // loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup(); // function show popup 
            }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
    });

    function loading() {
        $("div.loader").show();  
    }
    function closeloading() {
        $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
    }

    var popupStatus = 0; // set value

    function loadPopup() { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div         
        }   
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
            $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
        }
    }   
});
```

css.

```
#backgroundPopup { 
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
}
#toPopup {

    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -402px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

html is

```
<body>
      <a href="#" class="topopup"><button>type a name</button></a>
        <div id="toPopup">       
    <div> 
           <p><label>type a name</label><input type="text" value="" />
          </p>
          <button>save</button>
        </div> 
      </div> 
   </body>
```

1.The entered text should be displayed below the button`<button>type a name</button>`.

2.Popup box is displaying in fadding type,if i want to remove fadding while displaying popup,how to do.

Thanks

Comment: can you please give some more information about the code, as the div with #backgroundPopup id is not defined. Also, would you be able to replicate the code on jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `fadeIn()` to `show()` while displaying popup. I don't understand reason for adding delay while showing popup though.

```
$("a.topopup").click(function() {
            loading(); // loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup(); // function show popup 
            }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
    });

    function loading() {
        $("div.loader").show();  
    }
    function closeloading() {
        $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
    }

    var popupStatus = 0; // set value

    function loadPopup() { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup").show(); // fadein popup div         
        }   
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
            $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
        }
    }
```

I've added following method, that adds entered text below the button.

**UPDATE**

```
 $("#save").on("click",function(){
        $("a.topopup").after("<br/>" + $("#someId").val());
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut();  // for hiding popup with fade effect. 
    });
```

I've added id's to `save` button and text box also.

```
<a href="#" class="topopup"><button>type a name</button></a>
        <div id="toPopup">       
    <div> 
           <p><label>type a name</label><input type="text" value="" id="someId" />
          </p>
          <button id="save">save</button>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KfzJK/)

Comment: your demo i good.After clicking save button popup is still in visible state,how to make that popup disappear.

Comment: Just call `$("#toPopup").fadeOut();` inside `save` click handler if you want fade effect or else call `$("#toPopup").hide();` .

Comment: Rollback edit because it was too radical and should never have been approved.

Comment: Hi while clicking save button,the values are displayed in screen but popup is not disappearing,may i know how to implement that]

Comment: hi your answer is perfectly working fine in fiddle,while implementing in my project it is not giving any effect,is anything need to include,

Comment: alright, but what do mean by *not giving any effect* ? Is it working partially or nothing at all ? Are there any errors you see in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jquery dialog?

[http://jqueryui.com/dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

You can append to dialog what you want, for example forms and buttons.

define form

```
var firstselection = true;
var form = $('<div id="form"></div>')
        .html("<div id='example'>"<div id='divSceltaDest' align='center'><input type=text id='input'....
                    .....");
```

define buttons

```
dialbtn = {
    'call' : {
        text : 'What you want',
        click : function() {
            call();
        }
    },
    'cancel' : {
        text : 'Cancel',
        click : function() {
            form.dialog("close");
        }
    }
}
```

Prepare the dialog and associate all to a click button

```
form.dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    title : 'title',
    modal : true,
    width : "auto",
    height : "auto",
    autoResize : true,
    show : "fade",
    hide : "fade",
    position : 'top',
    close : function(ev, ui) {
        //alert('close');
        $(this).remove();
                ...   
    },
    buttons : dialbtn
});
```